# adding multiple image views by code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

am trying to add image views while looping in an array.. like this:

```
let v = [1,2,3]
w = self.playgroundimg.frame.width/3 - 48.89/2
h = self.playgroundimg.frame.height/4 - 17

for x in v {
  let imageName3 = "lineupcardbg"
  let image3 = UIImage(named: imageName3)
  let imageView3 = UIImageView(image: image3!)
  imageView3.frame = CGRect(x: w, y: h, width: 48.89, height: 70.15)
  self.playgroundimg.addSubview(imageView3)
  w = w + self.playgroundimg.frame.width/3 - 48.89 - 15
}
```

this is working fine, but the dimension of the imageview will be different from device to device .. like this:

iphonex:

[image]

iphone 7 plus:

[image]

as you can see the one in the middle is not centered to the one below it .. how to achieve this so the middle is in the center and the other two are beside it with some space? and be displayed the same in all sizes?

playgroundimg constraints:

[image]

Comment: How is `playgroundimg.frame` set?

Comment: @Carpsen90 from storyboard

Comment: I mean what are the autolayout constraints?

Comment: @Lama - use constraints and auto-layout... much, much, much easier than calculating positions.

Comment: @DonMag do you mean to do it in storyboard instead of code?

Comment: @Carpsen90 just posted it ...

Comment: @Lama - constraints and auto-layout are completely independent from Storyboards... Storyboards simply give you a visual design interface... but everything you do with constraints in Storyboards you can do from code.

Comment: @DonMag aha i see, can you please give me an example of how to do this by constraints in code?

Comment: @Lama - are you drawing the circles on a view? Or is that an image? If it's an image, are you stretching it based on view width? Or centering it? Or something else?

Comment: @DonMag its an image, and am centering and stretching it...

Comment: try to use bounds instead of frame when initializing w and h

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz i got the same result

Comment: @Lama - do you want variable horizontal spacing between the views, based on screen width? Or do you want the same spacing, just everything centered?

Comment: @DonMag based on the screen width so that it will be centered

Comment: What are the constraints of the `playgroundimg`'s superview ? is its width set programmatically?

Comment: @Carpsen90 yes based on the screen size the width will be modified

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do things in autolayout. One way to solve this is to set the `Leading` and `Trailing` autolayout constraints for the `playgroundimg` view. That would make `playgroundimg.frame.width` adapt to the device screen width. And make sure that the constraints of the playgroundimg's superview are set.

In Xcode it would look like this for example:

[image: constraints]

You are using `playgroundimg.frame.width` in calculating the `h` and `w` variables, which I would suggest changing their names to `x` and `y` respectively since they denote coordinates and not a width or height:

```
x = self.playgroundimg.frame.width/3 - 48.89/2
y = self.playgroundimg.frame.height/4 - 17
```

And update this line too :

```
x = x + self.playgroundimg.frame.width/3 - 48.89 - 15
```

Comment: all of what you have said beside renaming h and w is exactly what am doing right now ,,,

Comment: Did you set the Leading and Trailing autolayout constraints for the playgroundimg view?

Comment: why? i have updated it by posting the playgroundimg constraints

Comment: From the screen capture the leading and trailing constraints are not set. The playgroundimg.frame.width is apparently not adapting to the device size.

Comment: trailing and leading are not set to superview?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example - just to show how to use constraints from code.

You can paste this into a new playground page and run it to see the results.

Change the line:

```
get { return CGSize(width: 400, height: 400) }
```

to different sizes to see that the views remain centered.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class AlignViewController: UIViewController {

    override public var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
        get { return CGSize(width: 400, height: 400) }
        set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .green

        var theImageViews = [UIImageView]()

        for _ in 0..<4 {

            let imgView = RoundedImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
            imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imgView.backgroundColor = .white

            view.addSubview(imgView)

            // make all views the same size and width
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48.89),
                imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.15),
                ])

            theImageViews.append(imgView)

        }

        // for easy identification of which views we're referencing
        let leftView = theImageViews[0]
        let centerView = theImageViews[1]
        let rightView = theImageViews[2]
        let bottomView = theImageViews[3]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // "center view" will be centered horizontally, and a little above centered vertically
            centerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            centerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -25),

            // left view is aligned to top of center view, and 20-pts to the left
            leftView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.topAnchor),
            leftView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.leadingAnchor, constant: -20),

            // right view is aligned to top of center view, and 20-pts to the right
            rightView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.topAnchor),
            rightView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),

            // bottom view is centerX aligned to center view, and 20-pts below
            bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            bottomView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerView.centerXAnchor),

            ])

    }

}

let viewController = AlignViewController()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Comment: last two lines .. where to call them? inside viewdidload?

Comment: am sorry but what do you mean by playground page? x_x which page? is it the page i was using? or shall i create new class?

Comment: Are you not familiar with Swift Playgrounds? If you want to try this in a project, just add this code to your project ***except*** for the first two and last two lines. Then assign a new View Controller's class (in storyboard) to `AlignViewController` and run it.

Comment: Actually, delete the `override public var preferredContentSize:` section as well, if you're using this in a project.

Comment: no this is the first time i have heard about Swift Playgrounds, i will search about it and try to understand it